# Can you do SQL queries on the table generated by Django ORM?

Tags: python, sql, django, transactions, django-orm

I have a question concerning using Django ORM alongside SQL queries from outside django environment.
Namely I would like to make `SQL` queries on some tables managed by Django (tables corresponding to models).

Can you safely use SQL queries alongside `Django ORM`? Basically go around `Django ORM` but at the same time use `Django ORM`?

I guess there could be some problem with synchronization of the db state? I could not find anything in docs.

Comment: Any non manipulative queryies such as `SELECT` would be fine. However, you will run into migration errors when not using Django's provided migration system. Views which will depend on Models will become unstable when the Models do not perfectly reflect the database structure/schema. If you look at this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/. You can see Django's usage of Raw SQL SELECT queries.

Comment: The migrations and database structure/schema would be handled by Django exclusively.  If so SELECT UPDATE DELETE would be fine? Basically, we have too little time/ no people to rewrite project in node.js completely but at the same time not enough people to complete features in the project .

Comment: I am trying to find a way to reuse models and migrations with user auth from django, so as not rewrite that much and just use QueryBuilder on django tables, and delegate REST API to node.js team which is available at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there is enough information in django documentation, just rear through it. Db state would change only if you modify db, django does it by saving models, same as you would do with manual querying. Using select query does not affect your db.

[Django docs on almost raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/)

[Django docs on very raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

Comment: Please read [answer]. Nothing here is _wrong_, but it reads like "duh, RTFM, but yeah it's okay". A better answer would say "yes, it's okay because of X and Y, and here are some references to support my answer". Flip it around to focus on your answer.